# Panel larger than frame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a level editor for a platformer in Java. The issue is that I need to be able to edit wide levels, possibly multiple screens wide, but obviously I don't want to make a JFrame that is that wide. How can I make a panel inside the JFrame that is larger than the frame, and have a scroll bar for the panel that allows me to navigate the entire panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

you have look at [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) examples in the tutorial or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Scrollpane.htm)